# Same browser behavior under different OS versions

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, cross-browser, cross-platform

I was wondering if there is a difference in terms of website rendering, between IE 7, 8, 9 running under Windows XP, Vista and Windows 7.

Should I expect the same rendering output from IE 6, 7, 7, 9 running on XP, Vista and W7 or will there be differences?

I am planning to set up virtual machines to natively test web applications in each of the mentioned browsers. To save system memory, I was thinking of using several instances Windows XP as opposed to Windows Vista or 7.

The VM's will be running under VirtualBox.

I have asked around and most opinions suggest that there shouldn't be any differences, but I want to see what's your opinion.

I did see a few questions with users complaining that the same version of the browser does not work as expected on different operating systems, but most of the problems were because of bad browser settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just one thing comes to mind, there are differences in default fonts that come installed in operating systems, this could lead to different appearances if you use some fonts from newer Windows. But, since you are planning to run all on Windows XP, I guess this is not an issue in that case.

I just did a search and it seems there are some differences: [Differences in IE8 behavior between XP, Vista, Win7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611948/differences-in-ie8-behavior-between-xp-vista-win7)