# How does Internet Explorer 10 differ between Windows 7 and Windows 8 (Desktop/Metro)?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-7, windows-8, cross-browser

What are the differences between IE10 on Windows 7 and Windows 8 (Desktop mode and/or Metro mode).

Things like:

- rendering differences (including hardware acceleration, DX filters and media queries)
- JS differences (eg touch events, window resizing)
- plugin differences (do they sandbox Flash differently?)
- quirks (compatibility) mode differnces

Not so much things like:

- the ability to "[pin](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/04/03/pinned-sites-in-windows-8.aspx)" sites to the start screen in Windows 8 and other [Windows 8 integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh781490%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- the [user agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (`Windows NT 6.2` on Windows 8, `Windows NT 6.1` on Windows 7)

Comment: I thought they were using the same engine ([Trident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_(layout_engine)) 6.0)?

Comment: It is the same engine, but [in the past](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611948/differences-in-ie8-behavior-between-xp-vista-win7) there have been differences between the same IE version on different operating systems. Hopefully the differences with IE10 (if there are any) are minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft seem to sum it up pretty well here: [Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj819730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This looks good. "All differences involve touch-related APIs" - this sounds too good to be true.

Comment: This does seem to good to be true. I work in an older application (The code is bad, we all know it) we are trying to pull up to cross browser standards. I got form validation working in Win7/IE10, but it's not working in Win8/IE10, and it's basic jQuery. This tells me that more changed than the touch-related APIs. But I'm not surprised, it's expected of Microsoft to screw this type thing up.

Comment: I concur as above. Have ran into bugs that approach infinity in difficulty to solve because of the difference between Windows 7 and 8 that aren't "touch" related.

Comment: It is too good to be true, I'm getting layout bugs in Windows 7 IE10. I will report back once I've got my head around what's going on.

Comment: @dave1010 [responseXML](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2012/07/19/xmlhttprequest-responsexml-in-ie10-release-preview/), [DX filters](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2012/06/04/legacy-dx-filters-removed-from-ie10-release-preview/), [etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21947716/248058)