# Is IE10(+) identical on Windows 7 and Windows 8?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, windows-7, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I am developing on OS X. For testing I am using VirtualBox with windows VMs from http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

When testing my web applications, should I be testing in IE10 on both Win7 *and* Win8, or can I safely assume that IE10 behaves identically on both platforms and only test on Win7? And the same question goes for IE11.

Comment: I wouldn't make any assumptions about IE.X performing identically on any OS. You should define a lead platform, test heavily against it, and then perform smokes / sanity checks against any other platforms you choose to support.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516041/how-does-internet-explorer-10-differ-between-windows-7-and-windows-8-desktop-me`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they are not identical, but they should be the same for the common features that both support. IE10 and 11 on Windows 8 and 8.1 support a number of extra features that are not included on Windows 8. They mostly relate to touch and device hardware support. Windows 8.* is a touch friendly OS while Win7 is a more traditional OS that does not include robust touch support.

Differences in IE10 for Windows 7:

- The "Touch" token is never included in the UA string
- Gesture DOM events are not fired.
- Scroll, Scrolling Snap Points, and Zooming CSS properties are not supported
- touch-action CSS property is not supported
- `msMaxTouchPoints` returns 0

More details can be found in the [IE10 developer guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj819730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Additionally the following are not supported in IE10 for Xbox One:

- Geolocation API
- prompt() method
- Copy/Paste with JavaScript
- File API

More details can be found in the [Internet Explorer for Xbox One Developer Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn532261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Differences in IE11 for Windows 7:

- Device Orientation events are not supported
- Touch is not supported for HTML5 Drag and Drop
- Encrypted Media Extensions (DRM) is not supported
- High DPI is not supported (except the `devicePixelRatio` property)
- No Link highlighting
- No Media Source Extensions (media streaming, inc. MPEG Dash)
- Doesn’t support automatic phone number detection (converts phone like numbers into clickable link)
- No support for Screen Orientation API
- No support for SPDY protocol

More details can be found in the [IE11 developer guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn394063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#unsupported_features)

Comment: Well... that's comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

[Please visit Microsoft IE 10 Dev Guide:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj819730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[IE Guide:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg125382.aspx)